# Collapse/expand script won't work

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I am not experienced with Javascript coding. However, I am willing to learn.

I came across some tutorials for creating collapse/expand `<div>` blocks. I have tested the code with jsfiddle. You can check the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Evs2f/31/)

It works fine, disregard the styling.
However I can't figure out why the code doesn't work on the live website.

At first I have inserted all the code javascript and HTML in the WordPress Page editor. Then , I moved the javascript in the header. I saw something about the source of the code. I am not sure which is the source.

Here is the javascript code inserted in the header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/crimson/scripts/jquery.min.js">
function toggle2(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "expand";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "collapse";
    }
}

function toggle3(contentDiv, controlDiv) {
    if (contentDiv.constructor == Array) {
        for (i = 0; i < contentDiv.length; i++) {
            toggle2(contentDiv[i], controlDiv[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        toggle2(contentDiv, controlDiv);
    }
}​
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The HTML code is the same as on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evs2f/31/) HTML panel and it I display in a WordPress page.

Please tell me what wrong with this code? Is it the source of the javascript code?

Chrome console gives me the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle2 is not defined example.com:103
>   onclick

The big question is why the code works fine on jsfiddle either on mootools or jquery frameworks, and it doesn't work on the live site?

UPDATE:
I have updated the script tags. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Haha, simple problem, can't specify a `src` attribute on a script tag if you want it to execute the body.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your Javascript code in its own tags.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/crimson/scripts/jquery.min.js">
  <script type="text/javascript">

       YOUR CODE HERE

  </script>
```

Also, since you are using jQuery you need to use the ready() function like this:

```
       $(function(){
             YOUR CODE HERE
       });
```

---

```
  <a href="#" id="clickme">Click</a>  
  <div id="d1">Some content to hide</div>
```

In the head:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#clickme").toggle(function(){
               $("#d1").show();
           },
             function(){
                $("#d1").hide();
             }
           );
       });
  </script>
```

And of course, leave the reference to jQuery in the code.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response.This is the original tutorial page http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/. I don't see him using the ready() function.

Comment: OK. That tutorial is not using jQuery, but your submitted code includes the jQuery library. I assumed that you got that from the tutorial. Since you already have jQuery why not look at using jQuery to show and hide your divs.

Comment: I added a simple jQuery solution to the answer.

Comment: Yeah... It seems this is quite hard for me. I will think of other solution. Thanks for your support.

Comment: [Here](http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/) is a jquery tutorial that shows how to do it quite simply with just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but that link won't work. However, what I was asking here isn't a way for the code to work as it is? It works fine in jsfiffle either is jquery or mootools. I had enough trouble to figure out which goes where, and adding new functions just complicate this more. The bottom line is why the code works on jsfiddle and doesn't work on the live website?...

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems:

- An overlaping script tag
- You are using Mootools in your Jsfiddle, and jQuery in this sample
- You include jquery, but then do the animation in plain Javascript

Try this, correcting the script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/crimson/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle2(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "expand";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "collapse";
    }
}

function toggle3(contentDiv, controlDiv) {
    if (contentDiv.constructor == Array) {
        for (i = 0; i < contentDiv.length; i++) {
            toggle2(contentDiv[i], controlDiv[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        toggle2(contentDiv, controlDiv);
    }
}​
</script>
```

Comment: script tags are fine now. however the code won't work. In jsfiddle it works fine on mootools or jquery. So can you tell me why isn't working on the live website?

Comment: I would need to view the live website to detect what the problem is, it must be some kind of overlaping between your functions and some Javascript already present in the website, is the URL public so we can check ?